# Could you add two links in a <link href=""> tag in a single html page?

Tags: html, css

I wish to put an href that links to a CSS file and a website.
How can i connect these two links into a working  tag

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cookierel="stylesheet">
```

and

```
<link href="class17.css"
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure I understand, why not use 2 different links?

Like this:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cookie" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="class17.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

So - Answering your question: "Could you add two links in a  tag in a single html page?" - The answer is yes.

Answer (score 0):

The first link is a Google Font. You can have as many as you want.

To link your CSS/SCSS stylesheet just add another link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add multiple href's to the same link tag.

But you can add any number of link tags, as shown below:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cookie" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="class17.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css">
```

For details check [link tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp)